# twisted plugins / where to place them

Tags: python, twisted

I just started to work with twisted. I have some problems to understand the twisted plugin system.  What I would like to achieve is a folder/package in my app where I can place the plugins so that they are recognized by twisted when I start the reactor.

My project structure looks like the following:

```
MyProj
  |-__init__.py
  |-myproj
      |-__init__.py
      |-imatism.py
      |-twisted
            |-__init__.py
            |-plugins
                 |-simplematerial.py
```

Following the explanations in the doc [The Twisted Plugin System](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/core/howto/plugin.html), I am not sure if I place the plugins in the right package. There is no **init**.py in the plugins directory like described in the tutorial.
No errors are thrown when I start the reactor, but also `getPlugins(MyProj.myproj.imatism.IMaterial)` returns an empty list even if I instantiate two Objects of SimpleMaterial.

I also tried "Alternate Plugin Packages"(see link above) which ended in the same behavior - no errors but also no plugin output.

May be the plugins are loaded but do not get instantiated correctly or in the wrong place?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you really mean `init.py` in your question?  Or are those meant to be `__init__.py` files?

If the latter, then try changing your structure around to this:

```
MyProj
  |-myproj
      |-__init__.py
      |-imatism.py
      |-twisted
            |-plugins
                 |-simplematerial.py
```

Importantly, `__init__.py` makes a directory into a Python (import-style, not distribution-style) package.  Putting `__init__.py` into `MyProj` would make `import MyProj` a workable thing to write in your application code, but since you didn't have an `__init__.py` in `MyProj/myproj`, you wouldn't be able to `import MyProj.myproj` so most of your code would probably be inaccessible.  Also the redundancy in the name isn't very helpful.

I also removed the `__init__.py` from `MyProj/myproj/twisted` because that's just the way the Twisted plugin system works: you don't make that directory a Python package, it's just a regular directory.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `__init__.py` of course. I have edited the question.The problems was not about the imports. But you are right with `__init__` file in the `MyProj/myproj/twisted`, thats it. Thanks!

Comment: (Redundancy comes from the tutorial, but I think you are right about that.)